# Array Flip Error Message on All blocks

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

Edited:
I tried a lot to get warning solved, but end up with nothing. Can anyone look into this warning issue. Complete code is shown below:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)
          ->propertyCondition('status',1);
$results = $query->execute();
$node_ids = array_keys($results['node']);
$noddes = node_load_multiple($node_ids);
$fields = array_keys(field_info_instances('node', $content_type));
    foreach ($noddes as $keys => $node) {
            $item = array(
                'nid' => $node->nid,
                'title' => $node->title,
            );
    foreach ($fields as $name => $instance) {
            $items = field_get_items('node', $node, $instance);
            $item['fields'][$instance] = render_fields($items, $node, $instance);
        }

            $output_raw[] = $item;
    }
function render_fields($items, $node, $field_name) {
    $output_raw = field_view_value('node', $node, $field_name, $items[0]);

    return $output_raw;
}
```

The code above is edited code. I'm still facing this warning : **array_flip.** **How to solve this warning?????**

After quering node ids from database, I am using node_load_multiple to load all nodes. 
`print_r(node_load_multiple($node_id))` gives me

```
Array
(
    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vid] => 6
            [uid] => 1
            [title] => om
            ....
    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [vid] => 7
            [uid] => 1
            ...
```

when I use `field_view_value('node', $node, $field_name, $items[0]);` to render content to template file, I get the following error.

> Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in
>   DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 173 of
>   /var/../includes/entity.inc).

**line 173 of entity.inc conatins:**

```
$passed_ids = !empty($ids) ? array_flip($ids) : FALSE;
```

It(line 173) says:
*Create a new variable which is either a prepared version of the $ids array for later comparison with the entity cache, or FALSE if no $ids were passed. The $ids array is reduced as items are loaded from cache,
 and we need to know if it's empty for this reason to avoid querying the
database when all requested entities are loaded from cache.*

So, according to above line :173 , entity loader can either flip **id** or **string** and i am passing node ids in  `$passed_ids = !empty($ids) ? array_flip($ids) : FALSE;` .Then why am getting this warning????

**Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 173 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).**

```
$items = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => <p>Lorlita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

            [summary] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [safe_value] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

            [safe_summary] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

            [summary] => 
            [format] => filtered_html
            [safe_value] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

            [safe_summary] => 
        )

)



 $node = node_load_multiple($node_id); 
$field_name = "body";
```

Comment: What are you putting in `$node`, `$field_name` and `$items`? Without knowing how you generated content of these variables we cannot really know what error you made in generating content of these variables...

Comment: Please **[edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/167705/edit)** your question to provide details.

Comment: Please show the full code you are using, not fragments.

Comment: I edit my question. Please look into it.

Comment: please reopen this issue

Comment: Duplicate of: [Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet()](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/174018/1908)

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs because you are not passing a string or integer value, you are passing an array.

[`node_load_multiple`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) returns an array of nodes, so `$node_id` is probably an array containing multiple values, in your case.

To get the node object, you can use either `$node = node_load($nid);` or `$node = reset(node_load_multiple(array($nid)));`. The former is easier to load a single node.

Comment: This is that we can say about the code, since the OP doesn't show the code that initializes `$node_id`. I edited the answer: `$node_id` is an array containing more than one value, not just an array; if it were an array containing a single value, the function would return an array with a single item, if there is s node with that node ID.

Comment: @David, thanks for giving me a nice clue, but here when I do `$node = reset(node_load_multiple(array($nid)));`, it will convert my array of nodes to object and `reset` gives me only one node, the rest of the nodes get excluded. Can you give me a small hint, why it's happening?