# Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet()

Tags: 7, entities, database

I tried a lot to get this warning solved, but end up with nothing. Can anyone look into this warning issue.

```
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 175 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).
```

Comment: It works if $content_type is defined ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/entity-array_flip_warning-1102570-75_0.patch) is work for me. Try this out

Comment: Thanks a ton. But If you have seen warnings above mentioned, there are two types, first is `load()` and other one is `cacheGet()` type. `load()` one is done but what about                                                                                               `Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (line 388 of /var/www/html/std-build/httpdocs/includes/entity.inc).`

Comment: What should I do for Cache warning??

Comment: which drupal version are you using?

Comment: try this one path https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/drupal7.entity-system.1525176-143.patch this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is related mostly to the issue in your code or bug in the module which you're using.

Basically you should validate your [DrupalEntityControllerInterface](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/interface/DrupalEntityControllerInterface/7) implementation, and you should not patch your Drupal core as suggested by [@vgoradiya](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/174019/1908) since it's not a bug in Drupal core.

> Consensus seems to be that issues arise with bad data and should be corrected at the offending module level, not by adding a safeguard to DrupalDefaultEntityController that would mask deeper problems. Having an error here is a warning to developers that they are using the D7 APIs incorrectly. - [@jessebeach](https://www.drupal.org/node/1102570#comment-6540850)

So the challenge should be to identify which module implements [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/entity/7) incorrectly.

See also:

- [array_flip() [function.array-flip] issue in DrupalDefaultEntityController / entity.inc](https://www.drupal.org/node/1102570) which is not a bug, but closed as 'works as designed',
- [Entity API Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/878784),
- [How to create a new entity type](https://www.drupal.org/node/1026420)
- [Entity API](https://groups.drupal.org/entity-api) at Drupal Groups
- [Creating your own entities with Entity API](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api)

---

If you're developer of the module which causing the issue, please check the followings:

- Make sure your array won't contain NULL values, otherwise use the following trick:

  ```
  $arr = drupal_map_assoc($arr, function($v) { return (string) $v; });
  ```
- Check the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module (entity_example) for Developers how to implement entities.
- You're loading entities using the right `$ids` structure.
- Use debugger or `debug_backtrace()` to debug the issue.